# can't access a control in my form when I disable viewstate in asp.net and my viewstate is too bulky I don't want to enable it

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I want to disable my viewstate in a form because its too bulky (about 1mb per page) due to retrieving some data from database and in other place on the same form I want to access a control from my master page.
but when I set viewstate of Listview to false I'll get following error :

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

what should I do in this situation?
veiwstate is too damn bulky 
and here is what I've written for accessing particular control :

```
Control cc = Page.Master.FindControl("mainContent").FindControl("ListView1").FindControl("itemPlaceholderContainer");

        foreach (Control ListItemctrl in cc.Controls)
        {
            Control lblNewsId = ListItemctrl.FindControl("lblNewsID");
            if (lblNewsId != null)
            {
                Type t = lblNewsId.GetType();
                if (t.FullName == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label")
                {

                    string newsID = ((Label)lblNewsId).Text;

                    foreach (Control childCtrl in ListItemctrl.Controls)
                    {


                        CheckBox ctrlCB = childCtrl.FindControl("chkItem") as CheckBox;

                        if (ctrlCB.Checked)
                        {

                            //based on DDLAction we will do the things ;)


                        }
                        if (childCtrl.FindControl("chkItem") != null)
                            break;

                    }//end foreach childCtrl
                }
            }//end outer if

        }//end foreach listItenctrl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can disable viewstate for entire page and selectively enable it for your control as explained here

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153326/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/071410-1.aspx

Comment: thanks , but I have a ListView which in it I have a checkBox control and I need to check whether the checkbox is checked or not for a batch process task and when I disable viewstate I'll get the above error ... and if you read the above code you'll get the idea what should I access from master page.

Comment: what about putting Master page in charge by creating method for your logic there and calling it from your page. Btw the values of checkboxes are stored only on client side? If not, try to query data source instead

Comment: yeah the values are stroing only on client side , I guess I can change my strategy to ajax to avoid using viewstate :-?

Comment: yes I think it would be better that messing with code behind. Just set ClientIDMode to Predictable for checkboxes and you are done